# Query against Domain Classes should resolve against Entities

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, automapper, iqueryable

I am trying to build a generic repository that allows querying against domain classes.

My Repository interface looks like the following:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
    IQueryable<T> Query();
    void Add(T model);
    void Remove(T model);
}
```

Given I have an `UserEntity` entity framework class and a `User` domain class, I want to query against the `User`. The `UserEntity` should not be exposed to other services, because it should be internal to the Entity Framework layer.

A query like `userRepository.Query().Single(user => user.UserName == "Toni")` should return a `User` domain class. However internally it should query against an `IDbSet<UserEntity>` returned from my entity framework. The Expression Tree (which contains the `Single` query operation) should be attached to a query against `IDbSet<UserEntity>`. After querying against `IDbSet<UserEntity>` I want to convert the `UserEntity` to a `User` domain class. Is this possible?

I have in mind to cerate an `IQueryable` implementation for my `User` class that internally queries against `UserEntity`.

```
public class MappedEntityQuery<TModel, TEntity> : IQueryable<TModel>
{
}
```

Comment: `UserEntity` (POCO) should be your domain class. What you are trying to do can be characterized as building ORM on top of ORM.

Comment: The problem is that Entity Framework requires all entities to reside in the same project. I am trying to modulaize my ASP.NET MVC application by creating projects for each module. Thus I want domain classes for modules to reside in individual projects, which is not possible with EF.

Comment: Well, I would have to use MEF to load entities from different projects into a central DbContext. This is not possible as far as Code First is concerned, because Code First requires the convention to have all IDbSet<T> properties to access the tables to be in the DbContext. Thus loading them later does not work, as far as I know. However for this project I am using a Database First approach, which also does not allow to load compose a DbCOntext using entities from different projects, because you have to specify the Database metadata in one single metadata file (which will be embedded).

Comment: Since I am using a Model First EF approach, I wonder if the following would be possible: Define the model in the *.edmx file in a central Database Layer Project, then turn on DbContext code generation to generate entity classes. Then I would copy these entities to my separate projects for each module of my ASP.NET MVC application. After copying all entities to these projects I will disable the code generation strategy for the *.edmx. This way I have POCO domain classes that are indepenent  from the EF. Does this approach work? Would you recommend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Code First requires the convention to have all IDbSet properties to access the tables to be in the DbContext

That is not true. You don't need to have any set declared in the context if you provide mapping to the entities in the model builder. In your case you should declare mapping through `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` and `ComplexTypeConfiguration<T>` derived classes. You can create any `DbSet` instance of mapped entity type by calling `Set<T>()` on the context.

> However for this project I am using a Database First approach, which also does not allow to load compose a DbContext using entities from different projects, because you have to specify the Database metadata in one single metadata file (which will be embedded).

That is true only partially. EDMX metadata must be in the single file embedded in the main project but entity classes do not have to if you use your own instead of auto-generated. So your proposed approach should work.

But if you really want to achieve modularity you should not use EDMX. If you decide to add or change any module in the future it would require changing central project as well but that can affect all other modules - it breaks the idea of modularity, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation! I thought that both Model First and Database First require a Database and that Code First cannot be used with an existing database. Thus I thought that I cannot use `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` and `ComplexTypeConfiguration<T>`. How is the strategy calles (so I can dick deeper using Google)

Comment: I started to implement a Database First model using a single *.edmx file that lives in a single data layer project. Then I started to put the entity classes in other projects. I have learned that you must ensure the namespace and the type name must match and all properties (including navigation properties) must be present in the entity class. Otherwise an exception is being thrown that the Entity cannot be found (which caused me to think that this aprroach won't work).

Comment: That approach is  unfortunately called Code first as well but instead of creating a new database you are using an existing one (you just need to turn of the generation feature by setting initializer to null).

Comment: I think namespace can be different because EF uses only class name when matching types with entities in the diagram but they must have exactly same properties and navigation properties to  match.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I thought Code First requires the Metadata table to be present. And I can now confirm that the namespace of entity classes does not need to match (I have tested this now).

Comment: A related question: As far as I have tested it is impossible to use Code First Conventions without `EntityTypeConfiguration` because then you must have `IDbSet<T>` properties for all entites in the DbContext.  Would it be sufficient to use an empty `EntityTypeConfiguration` per enity class and let all properties (like keys, and foreign keys) resolve by conventions? Or could you only use either of this approaches (either convention based or using  `EntityTypeConfiguration`)